# Почему мой цикл for повторяется бесконечно?

Tags: c#, unity3d, for

Я имею код, который должен повторяться столько раз, сколько написано в движке, но когда я ставлю например любое число, мой цикл повторяется бесконечно, почему это?

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Stars : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera Camera;
    public GameObject Object;
    public float StarCount;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(CreateStars());
    }

    IEnumerator CreateStars()
    {
        Vector3 camTopLeftWorld = Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (0,1,Camera.nearClipPlane));
        Vector3 camTopRightWorld = Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (1,1,Camera.nearClipPlane));
        Vector3 camBottomLeftWorld = Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (0,0,Camera.nearClipPlane));

        for(int i = 0; i <= StarCount; i++)
        {
            GameObject Star = Instantiate(Object);

            Star.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(camTopLeftWorld.x, camTopRightWorld.x), Random.Range(camTopLeftWorld.y, camBottomLeftWorld.y));

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Так выглядит цикл. Переменную `StarCount` я задаю в самом *Unity*.

Comment: Покажи весь код, а не только эту часть

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вот весь код.

Comment: StarCount - должен быть float? Проверьте какое значение там появляется

Comment: Что такое `GameObject Object`, какого он типа, быть может у вас на нём висит этот же скрипт `Stars`. То есть механически этот скрипт вызывая `Instantiate` создает еще один экземпляр самого себя. Следующий - еще одну копию, и так до бесконечности. Индикатором этого может быть постоянное ускорение появления объектов. То есть не раз в секунду, а значительно быстрее. Перевесьте этот скрипт со звезды на другой обьект, который не надо размножать.

Comment: Еще сделайте количество целым числом `public int StarCount;`, а в цикле проверку вот так `i < StarCount;`. Тогда после того как разберетесь с тем, на чём именно должен висеть скрипт, объектов будет создано ровно столько, сколько указано.

Answer (score 2):

> Что такое `GameObject Object`, какого он типа, быть может у вас на нём висит этот же скрипт `Stars`. То есть механически этот скрипт вызывая `Instantiate` создает еще один экземпляр самого себя. Следующий - еще одну копию, и так до бесконечности. Индикатором этого может быть постоянное ускорение появления объектов. То есть не раз в секунду, а значительно быстрее. Перевесьте этот скрипт со звезды на другой обьект, который не надо размножать.

@aepot решил проблему. Сейчас мой скрипт висит на пустом Game Object'е и всё работает. Спасибо за решение!

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Когда ваша [репутация](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [проголосовать за вопросы и ответы](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), которые сочтёте полезными

Comment: @ΝNL993 не согласен. вполне решение проблемы. правда менее расписано, чем могло быть

Comment: @ΝNL993 так лучше?